# Where to find the proof for the isomorphism between the (2n-1)_th homotopy group of Aut(V) to Z?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am learning Bott-Seeley's comment article on the Callias' index theorem. They quoted a theorem, that is, $\pi_{2n-1}(Aut(V_{C}^{n}))\simeq Z$ or $\pi_{2n-1}(GL_n(C))\simeq Z$. Can you tell me the key to the proof for this theorem or direct me to some reference books? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since $U(n)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, they are homotopy equivalent, so $\pi_{2n-1}(GL_n(\mathbb{C}))=\pi_{2n-1}(U(n))$.

For any positive integer $k$, we have $U(n+k)/U(n+k-1)=S^{2n+2k-1}$, so we have the exact sequence of homotopy groups: $\pi_{2n}(S^{2n+2k-1})\rightarrow \pi_{2n-1}(U(n+k-1))\rightarrow \pi_{2n-1}(U(n+k))\rightarrow \pi_{2n-1}(S^{2n+2k-1})$.

Now $2n+2k-1>2n$, so $\pi_{2n}(S^{2n+2k-1})=\pi_{2n-1}(S^{2n+2k-1}) =0$, which means $\pi_{2n-1}(U(n+k))\cong\pi_{2n-1}(U(n+k-1))\cong\cdots\cong\pi_{2n-1}(U(n))$. So $\pi_{2n-1}(U)\cong \pi_{2n-1}(U(n))$.

Here comes the key point: By [Bott periodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity), $\pi_{2n-1}(U)\cong \pi_1(U)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, so $\pi_{2n-1}(U(n))\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @koejongen: You are welcome, welcome to MSE :)